# How to set a number of notification per day ?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I'm fronting a little issue with my app. 
 The user  choose a specific number of notification per day via a slider and the number will be stored the number in a variable( 10 notifications is the max) and he receive the notifications in a random time in the day.

But I don't know how can I set the number of notification wanted
in my code...

here's the code!

```
@IBAction func send(sender: AnyObject) {
    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.alertBody = myArray[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(myArray.count)))] // text that will be displayed in the notification
    notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: Double(arc4random_uniform(86400)))// 84600 Is the number of seconds in a day 
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName // play default sound
    notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.NSDayCalendarUnit// this line defines the interval at which the notification will be repeated

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Try using a for loop.

Comment: You should sync the number of notifications between app and server. I think user don't know how many they want to receive. And some notifications are important but out of limit. This is not good for user experience.

Comment: I'm using Local notification not a server. This app send quotes. The user can choose how much quotes he want to receive.